# Изменить значение переменной родительского класса в __construct()

Tags: php, ооп

Здравствуйте. Есть код

```
class class1{
    public $name='string';
}
class class2 extends class1{
    function __construct(){
        self::$name ='class2'; /*Вот где-то тут проблема*/
        echo $name;
    }
}
$one = new first();
```

Как при создании нового объекта Class2 переприсвоить переменную родительского класса Class1 и вывести его значение?

Чтобы в результате вывелась строка "class2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял к чему в вашем примере класс `first`, но если это опустить получается проблема в том что вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству как статическому, хотя оно таким не является, попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
class class1{
    public $name='string';
}
class class2 extends class1{
    function __construct(){
        $this->name = 'class2'; // Правильное обращение к свойству класса.
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

Так же советую почитать [Введение в ООП](http://php.net/manual/ru/oop5.intro.php) чтобы понимать что вообще тут происходит.

Comment: Да, обязательно почитаю, спасибо))